# How make get_next_post() return first post when viewing last one

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, navigation

I need a way to link to the first and the last post (CPT) created.

For example, I'm in the last post and if I click in "next" I should go to the first.

Now i have this

```
<?php
$next_post = get_next_post();

if ( ! empty( $next_post ) ) : ?>
  <div id="nextpost" >
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $next_post->ID ); ?>">
    <!-- <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $next_post->ID, 'thumbnail' ); ?> -->
    </a>
    <span class="nav-next">
      <?php next_post_link( '%link', __( 'Next project', 'twentyeleven' ) ); ?>
    </span>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I need something like `else: go to first post`. 
 I would do the same thing when I'm in the first post and when clicking on "previous" i go to the last.

## EDIT:

I found a snippet of code that set the order of the navigation through single-post like the `menu_order`, so maybe the solution now is different. 
Here the code of what I'm talking about

```
function square_adjacent_post_where($sql) {
  if ( !is_main_query() || !is_singular() )
    return $sql;

  $the_post = get_post( get_the_ID() );
  $patterns = array();
  $patterns[] = '/post_date/';
  $patterns[] = '/\'[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\'/';
  $replacements = array();
  $replacements[] = 'menu_order';
  $replacements[] = $the_post->menu_order;
  return preg_replace( $patterns, $replacements, $sql );
}
add_filter( 'get_next_post_where', 'square_adjacent_post_where' );
add_filter( 'get_previous_post_where', 'square_adjacent_post_where' );

function square_adjacent_post_sort($sql) {
  if ( !is_main_query() || !is_singular() )
    return $sql;

  $pattern = '/post_date/';
  $replacement = 'menu_order';
  return preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $sql );
}
add_filter( 'get_next_post_sort', 'square_adjacent_post_sort' );
add_filter( 'get_previous_post_sort', 'square_adjacent_post_sort' );
```

Comment: Just removed irrelevant text stuff to make code more readable.

Answer (score 4):

Firts / last post make sense if we have an order to refer to. `get_next_post()` function use post date to *decide* which post is the next. It optionally use also taxonomy, but once you use the function without any argument, only date is relevant, so the *first post* is **the most recent post in same post type**.

To get the most recent post you can use a new [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), [`get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) or [`wp_get_recent_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts).

Example using the latter:

```
<?php
$next_post = get_next_post();
if ( empty( $next_post ) ) {
  global $post;
  $args = array(
    'numberposts' => 1, 'post_type' => $post->post_type, 'post_status' => 'publish'
  );
  $recent = wp_get_recent_posts( $args, OBJECT );
  $next_post = ! empty( $recent ) ? array_shift( $recent ) : FALSE;
}

if ( ! empty( $next_post ) ) :
  // your code goes here
endif;
```

Comment: I added more info :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a helpful solution [here](https://www.forumming.com/question/6851/pagination-go-to-first-page-if-i-39-m-on-last-post) and expanded it to cover next and previous functions.

```
/*--------------------------------------*/
// Functions to loop previous and next posts
/*--------------------------------------*/
function get_previous_post_circle($in_same_cat = false, $excluded_categories = ''){
    $prev_post = get_previous_post($in_same_cat,$excluded_categories);
    if($prev_post){
        return $prev_post;
    }else{
        add_filter('get_previous_post_where','custom_get_previous_post_where');
        $prev_post = get_previous_post($in_same_cat,$excluded_categories);
        remove_filter('get_previous_post_where','custom_get_previous_post_where');
        if($prev_post){
            return $prev_post;
        }else{
            return '';
        }
    }
}

function custom_get_previous_post_where($where){
    $where=" WHERE ".implode(" AND ",array_slice(explode("AND",$where),1));
    return $where;
}

function get_next_post_circle($in_same_cat = false, $excluded_categories = ''){
    $next_post = get_next_post($in_same_cat,$excluded_categories);
    if($next_post){
        return $next_post;
    }else{
        add_filter('get_next_post_where','custom_get_next_post_where');
        $next_post = get_next_post($in_same_cat,$excluded_categories);
        remove_filter('get_next_post_where','custom_get_next_post_where');
        if($next_post){
            return $next_post;
        }else{
            return '';
        }
    }
}

function custom_get_next_post_where($where){
    $where=" WHERE ".implode(" AND ",array_slice(explode("AND",$where),1));
    return $where;
}
```

Usage:

```
    $next_post = get_next_post_circle();
    $prev_post = get_previous_post_circle();
```